# How to make interval of a second in executing a loop(C++)

Tags: c++

Actually, i am trying to make a stopwatch. Here i have made a loop to increase the value of an integer named seconds every time the loop executes. but it executes too fast. So, i want the loop to execute after every second. i've read some discussion on clock and time but i couldn't even understand that clearly. So, i wasn't able to use that in my code. [This haven't been long since i've started learning C++. So, I still don't understand advanced 'thing'.]

Here is the code:

```
     int main()
{

int looper=2;
int second=00;
while (looper=2){
    second++;
    cout<<second<<endl;}
```

Comment: What platform are you using? You can use the OS to fetch the time

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) or [sleep_until](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) (`C++11`) to accomplish your task (in `<thread>`).
And including `<chrono>` for time.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::this_thread;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    for (const auto& i : v) {
        cout << i << '\n';
        sleep_for(seconds(1));
        // or sleep_until(system_clock::now() + seconds(1));
    }
}
```

And in `C++14` with chrono literals:

```
sleep_for(1s);
```

Comment: Please seem my comment below

Answer (score 0):

This function relies on `<ctime>` to work:

```
#include <ctime>

//function that waits the specified number of seconds
void wait(double seconds) {
    clock_t start = clock();

    while (double((clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) < seconds) {
        //keep looping until number of seconds have passed
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
    int iFullDelay = 1000;

    DWORD start = GetTickCount();
    #define TIMES_TO_POLL_PER_SECOND 20

    for (int i = 0; i < TIMES_TO_POLL_PER_SECOND; i++)
    {
        Sleep(iFullDelay / TIMES_TO_POLL_PER_SECOND);
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    DWORD end = GetTickCount();

    printf("\r\n%d ms elapsed\r\n", end-start);
}
```

This will print out:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
1016 ms elapsed
```

So actually within 1 second we execute 20 times some operation - in this case printf. printf itself takes some time, so that's why 1016 ms is elapsed, not exactly 1000 ms = 1 s. So if you're executing something in a loop - you need to ensure it will not consume too much time, or somehow measure elapsed time.

Comment: This will drift over time due to the for loop and `printf` actually takes time.

Comment: Of course. But it depends on how much you want to drift - may be it's acceptable to have 0.01% drift. But if it's not - then use getTickCount and decrease time left. Simple math - isn't ?

end = GetTickCount();

if ( end - start > 1000 )
   printf("Time is now elapsed. return");

Comment: Best to do it right in the first place as it is simple math

Comment: You've asked that you don't understand how API's works - I've added you a sample application. Function itself cannot be written without full understanding what you want to do. It's also possible that in my sample printf execution will take internity - for example if I'll select something in console window - then it's not acceptable anymore to execute that function, then you need to use multithreading. So implementation depends on what you want to achieve.